# How do I convert time zones in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

In Athena I have timezones and datetimes stored in the database, and I would like to use the stored timezone to convert the datetimes

I can get this query to work

```
SELECT (my_date_time) AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles' AS converted_time
FROM table_one;
```

How can I replace the hard coded timezone with a value from a field in the table e.g.

```
SELECT (my_date_time) AT TIME ZONE my_timezone AS converted_time
FROM table_one;
```

I get this error when I try the second query

line 8:41: mismatched input 'my_timezone'. Expecting: 'ZONE'

Edit:
Adding to Guru Strons' answer this is how I used at_timezone

```
WITH dataset (t, tz) AS (
   SELECT
     table_one.my_date_time,
     table_two.timezone
   FROM table_one
   LEFT JOIN table_two ON table_one.id = table_two.table_one_id
 )
SELECT t, tz, at_timezone(t, tz) FROM dataset
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ahtena supports `at_timezone` function:

```sql
WITH dataset (t, tz) AS (
    VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2001-08-22 03:04:05.321 America/Los_Angeles', 'America/New_York')
)

select at_timezone(t, tz)
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2001-08-22 06:04:05.321 America/New_York |